# One JVM per application WAR in Jetty?

Tags: servlets, jetty, war

I'm using Jetty 8 to run some servlets. I have two (or more) applications that share source code, and I want to run them on the same port (i.e., 8080). I have placed two different WAR files into Jetty, `one.war` and `two.war`, so that I access them at, for example,

- `http://localhost:8080/one`
- `http://localhost:8080/two`

Both WARS contain an identical common JAR file (common utils). Does each WAR application get its own JVM? Really, I just want to be sure that the common JAR classes are entirely separate, since some of the classes are static and I need the two applications to obviously not share access to the same static class.

This seems obvious, and I seemed to confirm that it is the case that the common classes are loaded separately for each WAR with a simple test scenario (two identical WARs hosted in the same Jetty instance, but at different paths...see above). But I lack written documentation or confirmation that this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each WAR file will have its own class loader see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading. So you can safely use static classes.

Comment: Yup, this is standard Servlet Container behavior, all compliant Java servlet containers will isolate the webapps in their own classloader.  You can even have different wars with different servlet-api support levels.

Comment: A current documentation link: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html